# Какой компилятор использовать для Qt лучше для Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, компилятор

Какой компилятор использовать для Qt лучше для Windows?
На многих сайтах прочитал, что лучше использовать MinGW, но на нем не работает пространство имен QtWebEngine. В таком случае что делать и какой выбрать?

Comment: Причем здесь компилятор и пространство имен?

Comment: Классы QtWebEngine не поддерживают компилятор MinGW

Comment: Классы и не должны поддерживать какой-либо компилятор.

Comment: @FiqaTwin напишите тестовую программку, попробуете под MinGW и выложите ошибку.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow там зависимости от CEF и кучи системных библиотек. на Windows поддерживет только майкрософтские библиотеки исполнения,  а mingW  - своего рода анти-кросскомпилятор, который  имитирует  наличие линуксовых библиотек на Windows

Answer (score 2):

Де-факто, Qt 5.8 поддерживает только MSVC если вы хотите использовать Chromium.  Есть ограниченная поддрежка других компиляторов , но на практике все опять упирается в  движок QML и Chromium.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42725